# Android/Java Question: Seeking help in understanding a line of code from NotesList example

Tags: java, android, syntax

I just began re-studying java after graduating college 5years ago... so, much of the syntex in java looks unfamiliar.  I was wondering what `getIntent().getData()` means from the following line:

```
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(getIntent().getData(), PROJECTION,
null, null, NoteColumns.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

I remember calling methods by: `methodName();` 
and if I was to call a method in a different class I would use: `someClass.methodName();`
But, I can't recall how this works: `methodName().methodName()`.

I've searching the web for answers, but had no luck.

thanks in advance. ;)

Answer (score 2):

That is simply a chained method invocation. `getData()` is being called on the object returned by `getIntent()`.

Comment: Thanks alot!! This is exactly what I was wondering.. i kind of guessed that's what it was, but I just wanted to be 100% sure. thanks.